# POST request fails in Angular 7 but works in jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, rest, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a post request in Angular 7. The BE expects a JSON object according to this model:

**{ "event": {"type_id":"31", "location_id":"14"} }**

My code in Angular fails with 400 error:

```
addEvent$(): Observable<NewEvent> {
const body = { event: { type_id: 31, location_id: 14 }};
return this.http.post(this.eventsUrl, body, httpOptions)
.pipe(
  tap(
  (eventAdded) => console.log(`Added ${eventAdded}`),
  (error) => of(`Bad request: ${error}`)
  )
);}

const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})};
```

A similar POST request works OK in jQuery:

```
const data = { event: {type_id: 31, location_id: 14} };
$('.post').click(function(){
    $.post(Url, data, function(data, status) {
        console.log(data, status);
    });
});
```

The difference visible in dev tools *Network > Headers > Form Data* is that Angular attempts to send **{"event":{"type_id":31,"location_id":14}}** while jQuery sends **event%5Btype_id%5D=31&event%5Blocation_id%5D=14**

How do I make this work in Angular? (Changing to **'Content-Type': 'application/json'** didn't work too).

Comment: **UPD:** I've found the problem. In order for this to work, I had to send POST with 'Content-Type': 'application/json'. However, in this case Angular first sends OPTIONS request, which was not allowed for on the server side (returning 403). Once I had OPTIONS added to the headers, it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The body object is not a valid json representation for the post method.

Please wrap you body object as JSON.stringify(body) and hopefully it will work.

Also check the "accepts" header of the server method.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I've tried that, but it didn't work and, and the solution appeared to br different - I've just shared it in the **UPD** comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Perform that request without any httpOptions (by default httpClient will use application/json when the type of the body is an object). If it still 400's you, make absolutelly sure that you don't have any interceptors elsewhere on your application which might interfering.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, the problem was different - I've just shared the solution in the UPD comment above.